# calculate i-th power of a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a diagonal matrix of order $n$, and its non-null element, if it exists, it belongs to the $i$-th row is denoted by $\alpha_1$, then matrix $A$ is symbolized by $A=\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$. Find and prove a formula that simplifies the calculation of $A ^ k$ for all $k∈ \mathbb{N}$

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$A^2= \begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$A^3 = A^2 A^1=\begin{pmatrix} 4& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
This is good? How do I get the formula? what would? I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

If matrix $A$ is diagonal one, it can be written in the following form

$$
A = \sum_i A_{ii} e_i \, e_i^\mathsf{T}
$$

Then using the orthonormality property of the base vectors  $e_i^\mathsf{T} e_j = \delta_{ij}$, (where $\delta_{ij}$ is [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)), one can obtain

$$
A^2 = \left(\sum_i A_{ii} e_i e_i^\mathsf{T}\right)\left(\sum_j A_{jj} e_j e_j^\mathsf{T} \right) = \sum_{ij} A_{ii} A_{jj} e_i e_j^\mathsf{T} \delta_{ij} = \sum_i A_{ii}^2 e_i e_i^\mathsf{T}.
$$

Finally, in general if matrix is diagonal, then

$$A^n = \sum_i A_{ii}^n e_i e_i^\mathsf{T}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your calculation you might recognize a pattern, namely that the diagonal entries and $A^n$ are the $n$-th powers of the diagonal entries in $A$. It actually holds in general that for a diagonal matrix $D = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n)$, we have $D^k = \text{diag}(\lambda_1^k, \cdots \lambda_n^k)$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Can you prove this by induction?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Multiplying a matrix $A$ by a diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(\alpha_1\dots,\alpha_i,\dots ,\alpha_n)$ on the right amounts to multiply the $i$-column of $A$ by $\alpha_i$.

Multiplication by the same diagonal matrix on the left amounts to multiply the $i$-th row of $A$ by $\alpha_i$.

What can you deduce if $A=D$?